Modifying iOS Binary with IDA and Repackaging as IPA
I'm new to reverse engineering and could use some guidance from the community. I'm trying to modify a string in an iOS binary using IDA Pro and then repackage it into an IPA file for installation on my iPhone. Here's my setup and the steps I've taken so far:
Environment:

macOS
Jailbroken iPhone
IDA Pro

Steps:

I changed the IPA file extension to .zip and extracted it, revealing the Payload folder.
Within the extracted files, I right-clicked to show package contents, extracted the binary, and loaded it into IDA.
I switched to the Strings window by going to View -> Open subviews -> strings.
I searched for the string I wanted to modify, such as "xiaohongshu".
I double-clicked to enter Hex View.



I right-clicked to enter Edit mode and changed the string to the desired text, like "wwwwhongshu", then right-clicked to apply the change.



I exported the changes by going to Edit -> Patch program -> Apply patches to into file.
I replaced the original binary in the package from step 2 with the modified binary.
I repackaged the contents into an IPA file using the command:
zip -r newapp.ipa Payload
I installed the newapp.ipa on my iPhone using iTools.

However, when I try to open the newly installed app, it crashes. I'm not sure what's going wrong. I thought that since my phone is jailbroken and I've installed appSync, I shouldn't need to worry about signing issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your assistance.
Best regards,
darren

Jailbreaks don't neuter every single step of codesigning. Your page no longer matches its hash as recorded in the code signature, which will get the process killed when the page is faulted in (unless you happen to be using a checkm8-based jailbreak with appropriate kernel patches, but that is increasingly unlikely as time goes on). So you'll need to update the hash in the CodeDirectory. Either manually or by re-signing the binary (but make sure to keep its entitlements).

I truly appreciate your time and expertise. Could you provide a detailed guide or tutorial on how to re-sign binary files?

I imagine just codesign -d --entitlements - --xml Payload/Your.app/binary >ent.xml followed by codesign -s - --entitlements ent.xml Payload/Your.app should work (make sure to specify the .app on the second invocation, not the binary).

I think you are right. But I so sorry about that I don't understand those two commans.May be --xml or ent.xml is the file.  If you can tell me how can I fetch the --xml or ent.xml.
